# Operand type clash when compiling a native stored procedure in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Any idea why I can compile this stored procedure with the first Insert but not the second (or both)? The error message is:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure InsertExtPageWithXML, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 11]
> Operand type clash: numeric is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

THis is the SQL code:

```
--======================================================
-- Create Natively Compiled Stored Procedure Template
--======================================================

USE [PortalMO]
GO

-- Drop stored procedure if it already exists
IF OBJECT_ID('InsertExtPageWithXML','P') IS NOT NULL
   DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertExtPageWithXML]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertExtPageWithXML]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    -- (not inserted is the auto-generated UI [PK_Id], non-null, primary key..)
   (@1_Topic_PK uniqueidentifier = NULL, 
    @1_Path nvarchar(500) = "fix.me",
    @1_Title nvarchar(450) = "fix.me",
    @1_URL nvarchar(max) = "fix.me",
    @1_Priority tinyint = NULL,
    @1_Type nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @2_XMLfragment nvarchar(max) = "fix.me")
    -- (all of the types above are accurate to the schemas already in existence)
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH
(
 TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'us_english'
)

   --Insert statements for the stored procedure here
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[ExternalPage] (Topic_PK, Path, Title, URL, Priority, Type, LastUpdated) 
   VALUES (@1_Topic_PK, @1_Path, @1_Title, @1_URL, @1_Priority, @1_Type, GETDATE());

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[XML] (Associated_PK, Type, XMLfragment, LastUpdated) 
   VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), N'ExternalPage', @2_XMLfragment, GETDATE());
END
GO
```

Comment: It seems SCOPE_IDENTITY() is registering as a numeric.. placing a fake/temp one in it's place gets the statement to execute successfully..